# C++ Decimal to Roman Numeral converter - outputting incorrect output for no apparent reason

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to output "MCMLXXXIV" when it recieves the input of "1984". It is outputting "MDCCLXXIV."

Code seems to be correct thought. I have been over it many, many times and cannot figure our what I am doing wrong. Also cannot figure out how to get the input fail catch to work...it is commented out...any help would be great!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;


    string convert(int, string, string, string);


    int main()
    {

        int userNum = 0;
        const int MIN_NUM = 0;
        const int MAX_NUM = 3999;
        const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;
        string answers[ARRAY_SIZE] = { "", "", "", "", };

        cout << "Enter a negative number to end the program.\n";
        cout << "Enter an arabic number between 1 and 3999: ";
        cin >> userNum;

        while (userNum <= MIN_NUM || userNum >= MAX_NUM)
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid Value. Number must be between 1 and 3999: ";
            cin >> userNum;
        }

        if (userNum < 0)
        {
            cout << "Program ending due to user request.\n";
            EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }




       /*{
            cout << "enter an integer: ";
            if (cin >> num)
                      cout << "num: " << num << endl; }
            else 
            {
                   cin.clear(); 
                   cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); 
                   cout << "Bad data detected..." << endl;
                   system("pause");
                   system("cls");
                 }
            }
                     return 0;
            } */

        int thous = userNum / 1000;   // Extract digits and store as digit 
        cout << thous;                // also printing them out 

        int hund = userNum % 1000 / 100;
        cout << "hundreds:" << hund;

        int tens = userNum % 100 / 10;
        cout << "tens:" << tens;

        int ones = userNum % 10 / 1;
        cout << "Ones: " << ones << endl;

    /* Attempting to make four calls to a function named convert
       with returns a string and accepts arguments of the digit 
       from above extraction and the low, mid, and high, 
       numeral for that place (i.e. ones, tens, hundreds,
       attempting to store as a string. */

        answers[0] = convert(thous, "M", "M", "M");
        answers[1] = convert(hund, "C", "D", "M");
        answers[2] = convert(tens, "X", "L", "C");
        answers[3] = convert(ones, "I", "V", "X");

        cout << answers[0] << endl << answers[1] << endl << answers[2];
        cout << endl <<  answers[3] << endl;

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    string convert(int digit, string low, string mid, string high)
    {

        cout << digit << endl;

        if (digit == 1)
       {
            return low;
        }
        if (digit == 2)
        {
            return low + low;
        }
        if (digit == 3)
        {
            return low + low + low; 
        }
        if (digit == 4) 
         {
            return low + mid;
        }
        if (digit == 5)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if (digit == 6)
        {
            return mid + low;
        }
        if (digit == 7);
        {
            return mid + low + low;
        }
        if (digit == 8);
        {
            return mid + low + low + low;
        }
        if (digit == 9)
        {
            return low + high;
        }
        if (digit == 0)
        {
            return "";
        } 
      }
```

also the whole program is supposed to end when the user inputs a negative number. I was thinking that would be best done by putting the whole thing in a do - while loop, do int main, while userNum > 0?? Would this work?

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks folks.

Comment: After you get this to work, see how simple this actually can be: http://ideone.com/7uw2no  You don't need to call functions to "convert".  Roman numerals have a small number of components that you could just place in a static array and do a simple lookup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semicolons after the `if`s for 7 and 8 will prevent the proper encoding of 8 or 9.

Comment: this fixed the probem... the semi colons were giving back the incorrect values!! all good now.

Answer (score 5):

This is what compiler warnings are for. If I compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, I immediately get:

```
main.cpp:113:24: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
         if (digit == 7);
                        ^
main.cpp:117:24: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
         if (digit == 8);
                        ^
```

which is where your problem is. That entire function could be better rewritten as a `switch` statement, if that's the approach you want to take. Although there are better ways of doing roman numeral conversion.

I also get a warning for:

```
main.cpp:32:25: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
             EXIT_SUCCESS;
                         ^
```

since presumably you meant `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`